# adding consecutive numbers in a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, product

i have a vector and a scalar as input in a problem , the problem is to compute the largest product of n consecutive number of the vector and output the product and the index of the element of the vector that is the first term of the product. 
E.g vector =[ 1 2 3 4 5 6] , n=3
I'm supposed to get '3' (i e n) consecutive number of vector whose product is the largest .

in this case it will be 4*5*6
so output will be 120 and 4 as the index. 
now if vector has fewer than 'n' elements, the function outputon returns 0 and -1 as the output. 
please i need ideas on how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You can make a **simple implementation** with loops:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
w = 3
n = length(a)

maximum = -1

for i = 1:n-w
  p = prod(a(i:i+w))
  if (p > maximum) 
    maximum = p
  end 
end 

maximum
```

Or, you can use the **nlfilter** from the image processing palette.

```
a = []
w = 3

if (length(a) >= w)
  products = nlfilter(a, [1 w], @(x) prod(x))
  res = max(products)
else 
  res = -1
end
```

Comment: What happens if `a` contains a negative number? You probably want to use `-Inf` as your max.

Comment: Yes, of course it needs some tweaking depending on the borderline cases. I thought that if some of the numbers were negatives we should use an absolute value. But, it depends a lot on the real description of the problem :)

Comment: thanks guys for the guide, ill look through the comments and see what i can make of them

Comment: this is the result i get , it doesn't look right and i can pin where the problem is as i don't really understand the code

 >> [maximum,i]=  max_product ( [1     2     2     1     3     1],3)

maximum =

    12


i =

     3

Comment: Your code is strangly formatted and I can't understand your problem :s

Comment: what i mean is when i use [1 2 2 1 3 1] as a and 3 as w, i get 12 as the product . I'm supposed to get 6 and the index to be 3. the index is correct but the product is not .

Answer (score 1):

You can create the moving window from the answer of raryeng for the question [Matrix with sliding window elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800665/matrix-with-sliding-window-elements) and then appyl `cumprod` on the columns and take the max with its index.

```
myvec = [1 2 2 1 3 1];
n = 3;
ind = bsxfun(@plus, 1:n, (0:1:length(myvec)-n).')';
M = cumprod(myvec(ind));
[val,its_ind] = max(M(end,:));
```

You can encapsulate this with an if condition checking whether the length of `myvec` is larger than

Comment: works perfectly , but i don't understand the code, especially the bsxfun part. will about it. thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

You can compute the element-wise **logarithm** of your vector, so multiplication becomes addition; and sliding addition is just **convolution** with a window of ones:

```
function [m, p] = f(v, n)
if numel(v) < n
    m = -1;
    p = 0;
else
    c = conv(log(v(:)), ones(n,1), 'valid'); % convolution with vector of n ones
    [~, m] = max(c); % starting index of maximizing window
    p = prod(v(m+(0:n-1))); % corresponding product
end
```

Examples:

```
>> v = [1 2 3 4 5 6]; n = 3;
>> [m, p] = f(v,n)
m =
     4
p =
   120

>> v = [1 2 3 4 5 6]; n = 7;
>> [m, p] = f(v,n)
m =
    -1
p =
     0

>> v = [1 4 6 2 5 3]; n = 3;
>> [m, p] = f(v,n)
m =
     3
p =
    60
```

Comment: I'd appreciate a suggestion from the downvoter so that I can improve my answer